Taking the output of templatefile() as in input to be interpolated
I have a question about whether its possible to build a terraform data type (specifically a 'set of objects') using the rendered output of the templatefile() function .....and then use this output as an input value to be passed into a module? ..I cant seem to get it to work
So to explain , I have a pipelines.tmpl file that looks like this
pipelines_rendered = [
%{~ for p in pipelines  ~}
  {
    name                  = "${p.name}"
    project               = "blah"
    version               = "${p.ver}"
    branch                =  "something"
    description           =  "blah"
    ...
    ...
  },
%{~ endfor ~}
]

This is fed from a local that looks like this
locals {
  pipelines = [
    { name = "foo", ver = "1" },
    { name = "bar", ver = "1" },
    ...
  ]
}

The final rendered output of this templatefile() forms, what looks exactly like, the 'set of objects' structure that I need . I now want to feed this resultant 'set of objects' created by the template into a module as an input (to be interpolated) .. Specifically, as the value of a variable called  'pipelines_in'  (this variable is declared as type 'set of objects'  in the target module)
So as you can see below, when calling the module, I am invoking the templatefile() function to return the rendered output (set of objects) .. to form the value of the 'pipelines_in` variable
module "build_pipelines" {
  source        = "somewhere:/mymodule"
  pipelines_in     = templatefile("${path.module}/pipelines.tmpl", { pipelines = local.pipelines })
}

But whatever I try here, I seem to get the same error when running a plan
│ Error: Invalid value for input variable
│ 
│ The given value is not suitable for module.mymodule.var.pipelines
│ declared at
│ .terraform/modules/mymodule/terraform/variables.tf:35,1-21: set of
│ object required.

Is there is an issue when taking the output of templatefile() as in input to be interpolated ?
Is there another way i should be doing this (my brief is to remove the need for developers to have to build a full 'set of objects' , but instead just add a few variables and let the template build the full set of objects

templatefile() returns a string type which is why an error is being thrown for an invalid type for the parameter. The root cause would be better solved by migrating the for expression to the locals instead of invoking a templatefile function.

Terraform's templatefile function is for constructing strings based on a template, rather than constructing arbitrary data structures.
However, if you're willing to use an intermediate serialization format like JSON then you can effectively trick it into producing something you can turn into a non-string type.
For example, in your template you could write this:
${jsonencode([
  for p in pipelines : {
    name        = p.name
    project     = "blah"
    version     = p.ver
    branch      = "something"
    description = "blah"
  }  
])}

This is a kinda-strange template whose entire content is a single interpolation of a call to jsonencode. Therefore this template's result is a string containing JSON syntax representing an array of objects.
In your main configuration then you can use the opposite function jsondecode to parse that string back into the corresponding Terraform language type (a tuple of objects, which can automatically convert to a list of objects as long as all of the elements have the same object type):
module "build_pipelines" {
  source = "somewhere:/mymodule"

  pipelines_in = jsondecode(templatefile(
    "${path.module}/pipelines.tmpl",
    { pipelines = local.pipelines },
  ))
}

As far as the templatefile function is concerned, it's just returning a plain old string. But jsondecode then interprets it as JSON syntax to produce a more complex data structure, which you can then pass to your module.
To complete this, you'd then declare that pipelines_in input variable inside your module as having a list-of-objects type to make sure that the template is generating a data structure of the appropriate shape:
variable "pipelines_in" {
  type = list(object({
    name        = string
    project     = string
    version     = string
    branch      = string
    description = string
  }))
}

...and that way if you make a mistake in the template it'll get caught as an invalid type in the pipelines_in argument in your module block, rather than something probably-more-confusing in the guts of your module.
